# Paperclip save remote images without extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-extension

Here I have Controller

```
require 'open-uri'

user = User.new
url = "some_remote_image.jpg" #remote image WITH extension
user.image = open(url)
user.save
```

Model

```
has_attached_file :image,
  :styles => { :thumb => "25x25>", :large => "1000x1000>" }, 
  :path => ":rails_root/images/users/:id/:style/:hash.:extension",
  :url => "/images/users/:id/:style/:hash.:extension",
:hash_secret => "hash string"
```

This work, but images stores without extension, for ex. "some_remote_image."
If uploading images by post form everything uploading WITH extension. 
I'm confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by updating Paperclip to last github version and set image like this instead of user.image = open(url)

```
user.image = URI.parse(url)
```

Comment: I think you meant
     user.image = URI.parse(url)

Comment: I had the same issue and the above solution worked but as a side effect only one style(no thumbnail) is getting created. How to tackle that?

Answer (score 3):

In case if someone wants reverse thing - add extension to no extension files

```
  def besfore_save
    tempfile = data.queued_for_write[:original]
    unless tempfile.nil?
      extension = File.extname(tempfile.original_filename)
      if !extension || extension == ''
        mime = tempfile.content_type
        ext = Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[mime]
        self.data.instance_write :file_name, "#{tempfile.original_filename}#{ext}"
      end
    end

    true
  end
```